# Install SW that automatically updates together with Ubuntu updates

Tags: 20.04, updates

I want to add some software (For example Chrome or Virtual Box) to my Ubuntu system and I want to do so that when I update the system this software also updates. What steps or commands should I follow?

I saw and tried to use some script as this one, but I think it is already for previously installed SW.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you install the software from a PPA, then when that PPA is updated the software will also update.  Certainly this is true of Chrome, which does as part of it's installation, hook to a chrome PPA.

If you installed virtualbox from the standard PPAs then it will also update automatically.  If you installed using the most recent versions of VB from their website, and followed the instructions for adding the source to your sources list, it will automatically update.  Please be aware that under some unusual circumstances, new versions and updates of software as complex as VB don't always work perfectly - the versions in the Ubuntu repositories have a bit more compatibility testing done...

Comment: Also in my experience Ubuntu will ask when installing if you want an outside(stuff like chrome) software to be updated with the system.  Usually a small pop up box.

Comment: I run 16.04 18.04 and 20.04 never seen any such pop up for chrome it just does its thing and updates.

Comment: @crip659 I do my updates from the teminal and generally don't see the graphic pop-ups

Comment: It usually pop ups only when installing the first time, if not watching can probably be missed.  Does not happen during updating.  Can also check to see if the software is listed in 'software and updates' in other software tab.  A check mark should indicate it is updated with system.

Comment: @crip659 I suppose it might be a snap thing?  I also remove all of those...

Comment: Not snap that I know of.  Basically 3th party debs, like chrome that ask to be updated with system when installed.  Snaps are updated with system automatically.  Other software are usually outside of Ubuntu repos and need permission to be added to updates